# Dynamic Field Name in dynamic type in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am using Entity Framework and my table structure is as below.

Key, dec2000, dec2001, dec2002,... dec2020

so, while update in loop if for all columns in i have to specify the column name like,

```
for (int j = 0; j < intEndYear - intStartYear; j++)
{
  // Find value from FormCollection
  // Assign it to object
  OBJECT.DEC2000 = 1;
}
```

so, one way is i have to check for year and make condition check whether year = 2000 then use dec2000 field and so on.

So i tried to use Dynamic type so i can specify field name dynamically like

```
dynamic objLevel = objDetailSum.GetSingle(parameters);
```

so, while updating i am trying to do like

```
// trying to make field name
string stryear = "DEC" + year.ToString(); 
objLevel.stryear = 1; // should read objLevel.dec2000 = 1;
```

I know this will not work as i don't have strYear column in my table.

Question : Is there any other good way to handle this situation? so i don't have to check for each and every column and can use dynamic instead/.

Appreciate any direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information

```
//assuming "myInstance" is an instance of the EF class:
string strYear = "DEC"+year.ToString();
var pi =myInstance.GetType().GetProperty(styYear);
if (pi!=null)
{
  pi.SetValue(MyInstance,1);
}
```

Comment: ahh, i totally missed the Reflection part. thanks its working perfectly.